# d3js importing to angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

How can I import `d3js` int angular2 project? I installed the d3js using npm and added d3js to my systemJs however its giving me `traceur.js` error. I also tried just using latest cdn in script and did `import * as d3 from 'd3';` but that can't find the module.

SystemConfig.js,this setup gives me traceur.js error

```
var map = {
    'd3': 'node_modules/d3'
  };

var packages = {
    'd3': {main: 'index.js'},
  };
```

Comment: Well is the route correct ? What is the `traceur` error ? (Usually 404) Sure it's not `node_modules/d3/src/` ?

Comment: I think d3js is using index.js in the main directory as there's no src folder.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error when importing d3. If you installed d3 using es6 module like I did then setting the path to the bundle file will get rid of the error.

```
var map = {
  'd3': 'node_modules/d3/build'
};

var packages = {
  'd3': {main: 'index.js'},
};
```

After this you should be able to us d3 in the following way.

```
import d3 from 'd3';
```

I used the following page to help me figure this out. https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2900

Answer (score 2):

You could still use
`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

but import `'@types/d3'` into your devDependencies.
After you did this, you would be able to get the modules.
I use this in my ng5 application.

Comment: Works in Angular 9.

Answer (score 0):

Perform this step
1) move to the angular project folder 
run this on the terminal

```
 npm i d3
```

2) from your component class use the following import statement.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```